# How to replace html <a> tag with the text inside it using java

Tags: java, regex, string, href

I am fetching data from excel and value of fetched cell is

`"abc def (<a href = "https://www.example.com">terms and conditions apply</a>)"`

and I want to convert it into

```
"abc def (terms and conditions apply)"
```

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Your subject says href, message says def? Is it typo? What is actual string?

Comment: Search for the open parentheses and the ending '>' greater than symbol and erase the the contents in between them. That will only work if those values are consistent.

Comment: Or you can use parser and remove attribute for href and use element name and value to create string for any dynamic string

Comment: But my situation is I am reading a value from cell in excel. And its value is " abc def (<a href = "example.com">terms and conditions apply</a>)". But I want "abc def (terms and conditions apply)"

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "abc def (<a href = \"https://www.example.com\">terms and conditions apply</a>)";
    String a = s.replaceAll("<a(.*?)>|</a>", "");
```

Comment: But my situation is I am reading a value from cell in excel. And its value is " abc def (<a href = "example.com">terms and conditions apply</a>)". But I want "abc def (terms and conditions apply)"

Answer (score 0):

```
String s= "abc def (https://www.example.com\">terms and conditions apply)";
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('(')+1)+s.substring(s.indexOf('>')+1);
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks.. But my situation is I am reading a value from cell in excel. And its value is " abc def (<a href = "https://www.example.com">terms and conditions apply</a>)".
But I want "abc def (terms and conditions apply)".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "<a(.*)>(.*)<\\/a>";
        String string = "abc def (<a href = \"example.com\">terms and conditions apply</a>)";
        string = string.replaceAll(regex, "$2");
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

output is

```
abc def (terms and conditions apply)
```

and for input

`abc def (<a href="/some/some/some/href"># this is another sample #</a>) ghi`

output is

`abc def (# this is another sample #) ghi`

Comment: If there are multiple lines (with \n) between <a> and </a>, it might need modifications.